# Проверка на существование сообщения telebot/pytelegrambotapi

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

При попытке удалить несуществующее сообщение бот вылетает с ошибкой:

> "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message to delete not found"

код удаления сообщений (команду к боту и ответ бота) через кнопку:

```
bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.reply_to_message.id)
```

В обычной ситуации бот всё нормально удаляет.
Ещё пытался решить эту проблему таким образом но не работает:

```
        if call.message.message_id is None:
            print("message was actually deleted")
        else:
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
        if call.message.reply_to_message.id is None:
            print("message was actually deleted")
        else:
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.reply_to_message.id)
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Я точно не помню уже, но кажется, нужно инкрементировать или декрементировать идентификатор на 1, чтобы  его удалить (это работает не всегда). А вообще в качестве дебага - выведите в консоль сначала идентификатор сообщения, а потом когда удаляете через Inline - тоже выводите в консоль и смотрите или совпадают эти идентификаторы

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто добавить try и тогда если сообщение уже удалено, то бот не выключится, а выполнит except, туда можете написать ваши принты или что-то другое.

Синтаксис try :

```
try:
    # Тут удаление сообщения
except:
    print('message not found') # Выполнится при ошибке в блоке try
```